# React function with object params throws an unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a problem. I have the following function in React Native.

```
const HandleConfirmApplication = async (
  opts: { 
    isInvite: boolean,
    confirmationCheckValues: () => any,
    confirmPopUp: () => any,
    loadingApply: () => any,
    decision: () => any,
    updateState: () => any
  }
) => {
  const { 
    isInvite,
    confirmationCheckValues,
    confirmPopUp,
    loadingApply,
    decision,
    updateState 
  } = opts; //then do stuff
```

When i try to call it, i call it like:

```
onConfirm={async () =>
                HandleConfirmApplication({ 
                  opts.isInvite: true,
                  opts.confirmationCheckValues: this.props.confirmationCheckValues,
                  opts.confirmPopUp: this.props.onToggleConfirmPopUp,
                  opts.loadingApply: this.props.onToggleLoadingApply,
                  opts.decision: this.handleShiftInviteDecision('ACCEPT'),
                  opts.updateState: null

                })
              }
```

if i remove the object and just call them normally, it works, however when i tried to update the object so i can make the function params as an object it throws an error on each row saying Unexpected token  `',' expected ','`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a `.` in a property name isn't valid in JavaScript:

```js
console.log({
  opts.isInvite: 'example'
})
```

You should just pass the parameters themselves:

```js
HandleConfirmApplication({
  isInvite: ...,
  // ... rest of params
})
```

---

Note, technically you can have a `.` in a property name if you wrap it in quotes but that would give you an incorrect behavior in your particular code because you don't have any properties declared with that format.

```js
console.log({
    'opts.isInvite': 'this is fine'
})
```

Comment: Thanks. That seemed to be the issue